# Caption text over an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am sorry, this a newbie question. I want to display random pictures taken from a directory of my server and I want to display a text associated to each image (txt files in the same directory. Example: 1.jpg -> 1.txt; 2.jpg -> 2.txt...). I want that the text appear above the image, in a frame placed on the top of the image, only upon mouse hover on the image.

The javascript code, css and html codes can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Totoleheros/ES22a/

html code:

```
<img id="fullSize" onload="fixImage(this)" />
<div id="HOLDER">
<div id="theCaption"></div>
</div>
<img id="showImage" alt="random image" />
```

CSS code:

```
/* The first style is to hide the text*/
#theCaption {
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 331px;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
-moz-opacity:0;
-khtml-opacity: 0;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 3;
}
/*The send style is to show the text on hover*/
#theCaption:hover, #theCaption:active {
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 40px;
background-color: #eeeeee;
color: #000000;
overflow: hidden;
font-family: arial;
font-weight: normal;
filter:alpha(opacity=80);
-moz-opacity:0.8;
-khtml-opacity: 0.8;
opacity: 0.8;
z-index: 3;
font-size: 10px;
line-height: 0.9em;
padding-top: 2px;
padding-right: 2px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
padding-left: 2px;
}
```

javascript code:

```
function fixImage(image) {
// I want an to display an image of 200x331px taken from a directory of image of various dimensions
var show = document.getElementById("showImage");
if (image.height > image.width) {
    show.style.height = "331px";
    show.style.width = Math.round((image.width / image.height) * 331) + "px";
} else {
    show.style.width = "200px";
    show.style.height = Math.round((image.height / image.width) * 200) + "px";
}

show.src = image.src;
show.style.visibility = "visible";
}

var MAXPICTURENUMBER = 166; // or whatever you choose
var rn = 1 + Math.floor(MAXPICTURENUMBER * Math.random());
// Here I point to the directory containing the images and the caption
var url = "http://www.test.fr/Images/RandomPictures/" + rn + ".jpg";
var caption = "http://www.test.fr/Images/RandomPictures/" + rn + ".txt";

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", caption, false);
xmlhttp.send();
captionText = xmlhttp.responseText;

window.onload = function () {
document.getElementById("theCaption").innerHTML = captionText;
document.getElementById("fullSize").src = url;
}
```

I am sure that there is a much cleaner/smarter solution than the one I am using, but remember, I'm a newbie.

My issue: this is almost working except that the text sometimes disappear according to the mouse position. How can I fix that?

Thkx in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the image and the caption in the same container. Something like

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="image" src="image.png" />
    <div class="caption">The caption</div>
</div>
```

and in css

```
.caption{position:relative; top:-20px; height:20px; display:none;}
.container:hover .caption{display:block;}
```

you can obviously style however.

EDIT:  here's the final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ES22a/5 part of the problem was a jQuery conflict so there's also a `jQuery.noConflict();` in the head.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, this solution turns the 'caption' into an class selector instead of an id selector. The problem is that I have the following code in my javascript: document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = captionText; It doesn't work if I use : document.getElementByClassName("theCaption").innerHTML = captionText;...

Comment: If you use jQuery, you could do `$('.caption').html(captionText);` also, I was using class arbitrarily. You could use the `"id=caption"` instead. just change the styles from `.caption` to `#caption`

Comment: I tried with #caption but it does not work. I believe this is because you cannot use the ID selector for items appearing in more than 1 CSS declaration, which is the case for the caption style...(I do not know anything about jQuery, is it easy to implement in my case?)

Comment: Any further helping hint?

Comment: Yes. It looks like you are doing way too much work. I would definitely  use jQuery. It's not absolutely necessary but it would make your life easier. Just link the google jquery library found here https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery I prefer usin 1.7 because they dropped IE 8 support with 1.8. anyways link it and use `$('.caption').html(captionText);` instead of `document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = captionText; `

Comment: Thanks. I have started to use the jQuery. I am still having hard time to make it work properly. The script is running in a sidebar which is 'imported' (@import with PlusKit in rapid weaver) in the various pages of my site. While the sidebar page display my images and caption as wanted, they are not displayed at all when the sidebar is called from my various pages (I have included the javascript and jQuery script in the sidebar 'calling' pages). I do not understand why...???

Comment: There are a lot of reasons that could be happening. Most likely it's that the library is not being loaded. Just include jquery in the head of all pages. Are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: Yes, the jquery was included in the head of all pages. I have this error message: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating '$('.theCaption').html'). My javascript code related to this error is this one: 
window.onload = 
   function() { 
 $('.theCaption').html(captionText);
 $('.fullSize').prop('src',url);
   }
 
 
A puzzling issue for me.Thank you for your help.

Comment: My htlm code:

<img class="fullSize" onload="fixImage(this)" />
<div class="HOLDER">
    <div class="theCaption"></div>
    <img id="showImage" alt="random image" />
</div>

Comment: My javascript code (only the section that changed compared to my initial post, the rest of the code is the same): 
 
window.onload = 
   function() { 
 $('.theCaption').html(captionText);
 $('.fullSize').prop('src',url);
}

Comment: My CSS code Part 1:
    
#showImage {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 331px; width: 200px; 
    visibility: hidden; 
    z-index: 1;
}

.HOLDER { 
    position: relative;
}

Comment: My CSS code Part 2: 

.theCaption {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 200px; height: 40px; 
    background-color: #eeeeee; color: #000000;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: arial; font-weight: normal;
        filter:alpha(opacity=80);
        -moz-opacity:0.8;
        -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
        opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 2;
font-size: 10px;
line-height: 0.9em;
padding-top: 2px;
padding-right: 2px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
padding-left: 2px;
 display: none;
}

.HOLDER:hover .theCaption{display:block;}

.fullSize {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; left: 0px; 
    visibility: hidden;
}

Comment: And finally, th jquery in the head of each pages:

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Sounds like it's a timing issue. Wanna make a JSfiddle with your most recent code and link it here? I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: I have updated the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Totoleheros/ES22a/2/.In addition, I have this code in the head of all pages: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>. The time you are spending in trying to help me is very much appreciated!!! Best.

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/ES22a/3/) should help. Timing is a huge part of javascript especially when you get into asynchronous requests. One way this project would become MUCH simpler is if you used something like php to load the image and caption. You could then store the captions in the database and even resize the images on the server. Let me know if that works for you. It's hard to tell without actually urls to pull from.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your solution is not working. I do not have any image or text displayed in the calling pages nor in the sidebar page that is called. No errors reported in the browser inspector. I don't feel like switching everything toward PHP, too much work for me for just having the text displayed on hover. I think that I now give up with the text displayed regardless of flying over the image or not. Thank you again for your help!!

Comment: I have hard time giving up since I believe I am close from the solution, as can be seen [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ES22a/4/). But this is not working on my real page (www.lvts.fr) and I have this error now:TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating '$('.theCaption').html'). Any ideas of what is going wrong?

Comment: If that doesn't work, then you're having issues loading jQuery. Then you'll have to check if you have any other libraries causing a conflict. In which case, check out `jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: Alleluia!! It worked with the jQuery.noConflict(); trick. This how I dealed: I placed this code in the header:
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jq=jQuery.noConflict();
</script>`

Then, replaced my javascript/jquery code line as follows: 
`window.onload = function() {  jq('.theCaption').html(xmlhttp.responseText); jq('.fullSize').prop('src',url); };`
Thank you very much MrJellyhands, I owe you a beer!! Best

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad it worked for you. Maybe you can accept my answer?