# Caption text over an image: not working anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

This question is related to a previous post where the problem was temporarily solved: [Caption text over an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120486/caption-text-over-an-image/29905875#29905875).

I had to move my website to a new server where the script doesn't work anymore. The purpose is to load a random image from a folder on my website and to display over the image a related paired text (image1.jpg & text1.txt).

After the migration of the site, nor the images or the text would display. I could get the image displayed again by changing this line of code:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", caption, false);

->

xmlhttp.open("GET", caption, true);
```

This has fixed the problem of the images but the attached text is still not displayed.

The updated JSfiddle is there: http://jsfiddle.net/Totoleheros/ES22a/7/.

html:

```
<img class="fullSize" onload="fixImage(this)" />
<div class="HOLDER">
    <div class="theCaption"></div>
    <img id="showImage" alt="random image" />
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function fixImage( image )
{
    // change calculations to match your needs
    var show = document.getElementById("showImage");
    if ( image.height > image.width )
    {
        show.style.height = "331px";
        show.style.width = Math.round( (image.width / image.height) * 331 ) + "px";
    } else {
        show.style.width = "200px";
        show.style.height = Math.round( (image.height / image.width) * 200 ) + "px";
    }



    show.src = image.src;
    show.style.visibility = "visible";
}

var MAXPICTURENUMBER = 166; // or whatever you choose
var rn = 1 + Math.floor( MAXPICTURENUMBER * Math.random() );
var url ="http://www.lvts.fr/Images/RandomPictures/" + rn + ".jpg";
var caption ="http://www.lvts.fr/Images/RandomPictures/" + rn + ".txt";

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", caption, true);
xmlhttp.send();

window.onload = function() {    jq('.theCaption').html(xmlhttp.responseText); jq('.fullSize').prop('src',url); };

$mirage(document).ready(function(){
    $mirage('body').unbind('mouseenter');
    var mirageMenuConfig = { sensitivity: 3, interval: 30, over: revealMainMenuChildren, timeout: 500, out: hideMainMenuChildren };
    function revealMainMenuChildren(){  $mirage(this).children("ul").css('opacity','1').slideDown(300); }
    function hideMainMenuChildren(){     $mirage(this).children("ul").fadeTo(300, 0).slideUp(300); }    
    $mirage("#nav ul ul").parent().addClass("ddarrow");
    $mirage("#nav ul ul").parent().append("<span></span>");
    $mirage("#nav ul ul").css({ display: "none" }); 
    $mirage("#nav ul li").hoverIntent(mirageMenuConfig);
});
```

CSS:

```
#showImage {
     display: block;
    height: 331px; width: 200px; 
    visibility: hidden; 
    z-index: 1;
}

.HOLDER { 
    position: relative;
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.theCaption {
    position: absolute; 

    width: 196px; height: 40px; 
    background-color: #eeeeee; color: #000000;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: arial; font-weight: normal;
        filter:alpha(opacity=80);
        -moz-opacity:0.8;
        -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
        opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 2;
font-size: 10px;
line-height: 0.9em;
padding-top: 2px;
padding-right: 2px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
padding-left: 2px;
    display: none;
}

.HOLDER:hover .theCaption {display:block;}

.fullSize {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; left: 0px; 
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I don't understand why moving the website has generated this issue. Any help would be very much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

That's because the speed of the connection to the server changed - it got slower.

AJAX request are asynchronous. What happens is that you send the request, read the result and then the response from the server comes in. Use this code instead:

```
var caption ="http://www.lvts.fr/Images/RandomPictures/" + rn + ".txt";

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax(caption, {
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('data', data);
            $('.theCaption').html(data);
        }
    });

    $('.fullSize').prop('src',url);
});
```

jQuery will prepare everything to call the `success` callback when the server response comes in. See http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

And you should use [`$( document ).ready();`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) instead of `window.onload`
Note: For this to work, the document must be served from `www.lvts.fr` as well or you'll get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.lvts.fr/Images/RandomPictures/79.txt. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: First, thank you very much for your reply. I tried your solution but the text is still not displayed. However, I'm not sure that I've understood your note correctly. Which is the document that must be served from lvts.fr?

Comment: [Same-origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) applies: You can't use AJAX to load arbitrary data from any server. The code above only works when the domain of the document (as in the location bar of the browser) and the domain of the AJAX request are the same.

Comment: This is the case for me: the image and text files are hosted on my server.

Comment: In that case, check the JavaScript console of your browser. It should display the data which the server returns. You can also add an error handler to the code to see failures.